# Turn on Packet Data in dual sim phone

Tags: android, android-internet

I'm using this function for turning on the packet data:

```
public static void setDataNetworkEnable(Context mContext) {
    try {
        ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        Class<?> conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
        Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass
                .getDeclaredField("mService");
        iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
        Class<?> iConnectivityManagerClass = Class
                .forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
        Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass
                .getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work in dual sim phone...

does any solution exist?

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: No, I'm waiting for turning on packet data, but it can't become on.

Comment: I have checked this function for galaxy gio , and it worked but in sumsong nexus and dual sim phones doesn't work